# How add to the geckofx automatic connection/authentication to socks5 or at least http proxy

Tags: c#, authentication, proxy, socks, geckofx

In the gecko about:config i found this preferences, but i not found login/username, password.

```
Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.type"] = 1;
Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.socks"] = Ip;
Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.socks_port"] = Port;
Gecko.GeckoPreferences.User["network.proxy.socks_version"] = 5;
```

Comment: The connection is probably using a Window Credentials which is associated with the user windows login.